How to get all characters of some font in libharu?
For example, "Arial Unicode MS" font supports 38,911 characters, how can I output all to a PDF file?
I checked document but there no some direct function to do this.

Use a C++ PDF library to generate a PDF document. This is not part of C++.

@Jean-BaptisteYunès I think the question was how to see all 38911 characters as in which ones exist?

@darclander yes.

Disclaimer that I haven't worked a lot with libharu but assuming something like the code below you could loop over a range of characters and store the ones that exist within the font? The problem is that you wouldn't actually get all of the characters in a font but you would actively search for all of them. In the example below we loop from 0 to 0xFFFF (65535) unicode characters.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <hpdf.h>

int main() {
    std::vector<HPDF_UNICODE> availableChars;
    auto pdf = std::unique_ptr<HPDF_Doc, decltype(&HPDF_Free)>(HPDF_New(nullptr, nullptr), &HPDF_Free);
    auto font = HPDF_GetFont(pdf.get(), "Arial Unicode MS", nullptr);

    for (HPDF_UNICODE unicode = 0; unicode <= 0xFFFF; ++unicode) {  
        HPDF_UNICODE cid = HPDF_Font_GetGID(font, unicode);
        if (cid != 0) {
            // You could probably print it here as well and remove the loop on line 20.
            availableChars.push_back(unicode); 
        }
    }

    for (HPDF_UNICODE c : availableChars) {
        std::cout << static_cast<char>(c) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

